# Join tables and summarize rows based on condition

Tags: postgresql, join, count, sum

I have two tables.

- One containing countries with an ID and the geometry
- The other containing customers with a name, geometry and a boolean value showing if they are active or not.

  ```
  Countries
  iD     name     geometry
  1634   UK       xxx
  2357   USA      xxx
  3345   Mexico   xxx
  4694   Italy    xxx


  Customers
  name         geometry    statusActive
  Hernandez    xxx         TRUE
  Taylor       xxx         FALSE
  Monte        xxx         TRUE
  Winter       xxx         TRUE
  Best         xxx         TRUE
  Twist        xxx         TRUE
  ```

I want to find out, how many active customers there are in each country.

Step 1 - Join data: I could join the two tables based on the geometry. With ST_Contains I can test, which of the customers is located in which country. This works out well. I get as result a table from Customers which has additionally the column of the country ID. In addition, only customers with an active status are returned.

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT customers.*, countries.id
FROM customers
JOIN countries ON ST_Contains(countries.geometry, customers.geometry)
WHERE customers.statusActive IS TRUE
```

This is the resulting table:

```
Customers
name        geometry    statusActive    id
Hernandez   xxx         TRUE            1634
Monte       xxx         TRUE            4694
Winter      xxx         TRUE            2357
Best        xxx         TRUE            2357
Twist       xxx         TRUE            4694
```

Step 2- Sum up the customers in each country.
I do not know how I can achieve this. I already tried to use GROUP BY based on the country ID, but this results in an error, that I have to include all columns from the SELECT statement. When I remove the customers.* (all fields from customers) from the SELECT, the query is running forever.
This is how the desired result should look like:

```
NumberActiveUsers   ID
1                   1634
2                   2357
0                   3345    
2                   4694
```

Do I need another function to sum up the entries, or is GROUP BY the correct function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit some parts to get a query, as i didn#t have geommetry

> ```
> CREATE TABLE countries (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "name" VARCHAR(6),
>   "geometry" VARCHAR(3)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO countries
>   ("id", "name", "geometry")
> VALUES
>   ('1634', 'UK', 'xxx'),
>   ('2357', 'USA', 'yyy'),
>   ('3345', 'Mexico', 'zzz'),
>   ('4694', 'Italy', 'aaa');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customers (
>   "name" VARCHAR(9),
>   "geometry" VARCHAR(3),
>   "statusActive" boolean
> );
>
> INSERT INTO customers
>   ("name", "geometry", "statusActive")
> VALUES
>   ('Hernandez', 'xxx', 'TRUE'),
>   ('Taylor', 'xxx', 'FALSE'),
>   ('Monte', 'aaa', 'TRUE'),
>   ('Winter', 'yyy', 'TRUE'),
>   ('Best', 'yyy', 'TRUE'),
>   ('Twist', 'aaa', 'TRUE');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  COALESCE(countr,0) NumberActiveUsers ,co.id
> FROM
> (SELECT countries.id, Count(*) countr
> FROM customers
> JOIN countries ON countries.geometry =  customers.geometry
> WHERE "customers"."statusActive" IS TRUE
> GROUP BY countries.id) t1 RIGHT JOIN countries co ON t1.id = co.id
> ```
>
> ```
> numberactiveusers |   id
> ----------------: | ---:
>                 1 | 1634
>                 2 | 2357
>                 0 | 3345
>                 2 | 4694
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9026f89ee0f9f4c1c6cdc7e5fb40585e)*

Comment: wow, thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!!